# Is there a way to target certain Api's in a drawable.xml file?

Tags: android, api, drawable

I created a custom drawable using ripple, which only targets api 21 and above, I know its possible to do it programmatically but is there a way to do it in the drawable itself?

I also tried making a separate folder for higher api's which I heard could be done with layouts but no luck anything is apricated thanks.

Comment: `do it in the drawable itself?` Didn't quite get it . if you want to create only a single drawable then create a `Selector` drawable . If not then explain your problem .

Comment: @ADM that's actually brilliant I don't know how I didn't think of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple resources for different `API` version and let Android choose one of them based on device's `API` version. Create a new `drawable.xml` file but choose `API` version 21 as a qualifier and put your code on that. Create another `drawable.xml` with no version qualifier and put another code which runs on pre 21 version.

Comment: Your welcome. Please consider this topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and don't forget vote up

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have already tried it, but this should work.  Create a drawable-v21 in your res folder.  This should target API 21 and above (or if you have another higher API drawable folder i.e. drawable-v24 your 21 will target from 21 to 23).  Place your drawables for that level in this new directory

Comment: yea I tried creating a new folder but its not allowing ' - ' which is frustrating because this was a possible solution I had but didn't get the chance to try.

Comment: Try creating the directory in your explorer window

Comment: Got it to work I was creating a resource file not a directory, im new to android studio before I was using AIDE for a couple of years prior to this week thanks for the help

Comment: No worries. Easy mistake to make. If the answer has helped, would be great if you can mark it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sth like this:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
```

and then show your drawable.

Comment: yea that was one of my options, but I wanted to see if I was able to do it in only the drawable.xml file itself